# How to check for empty inputs in java scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

After some digging, I have not been able to find a satisfactory way to achieve a condition in a do-while loop, so that the scanner will ignore empty inputs.

Attempted code:

```java
String name = "";
boolean flag_name= false;
do{
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" is not a valid name...\n", number);
    }else{
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        if(!name.equals("")){
            if(name.length() <= 2){
                System.out.println("The name is too short (min: 3)...");
            }else if(name.length >= 20){
                System.out.println("The name is too long (max: 20)...");
            }else{
                flag_name = true;
            }
        }
    }
}while(!flag_name);
```

expected output:

```sh
Name: 
Name:
Name:
Name:
Name:
Name: willy
Age:
```

actual output:

```sh
Name: 




willy
Name: Name: Name: Name: Name: Age:
```

Comment: Your code crashes because missing `()` in `name.length >= 20`,  should be `name.length() >= 20`

Comment: This code (correct for `()`) works fine for me.  With what input does it not work?

Comment: FYI: You can replace `name.equals("")` with a call to `String#isEmpty`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally came up with the following solution:

```java
// Regex validation of number
public static boolean isNumeric(String str){
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}

// Validation of the string input with custom error messages.
public static boolean isValidName(String name){
    if(Utils.isNumeric(name)){
        System.out.printf("\"%s\" Is not a valid name.\n\n", name);
    }else{
        if(name.length() < 3){
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" Too short... (min 3)\n\n", name);
        }else if(name.length() > 20){
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" Too long... (max 20)\n\n", name);
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Ask for input code block
String name;
do{
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();
    if(!name.isEmpty()){
        if(Utils.isValidName(name)){
            break;
        }
    }
}while(true);
```

0. Saved my input in a variable and validate from there.
1. Implemented a regex mehod for checking not only integers but any kind of number.
2. Separated the validation of the actual input with custom error messages on another method.
3. .isEmpty() method for discarding empty inputs (original question).

Answer (score 0):

I would say your logic is flawed. Instead of looping through like this, consider to break down your method into multiple function.

Let me write an algorithm

```
static boolean isValidName(String input) {
    /*
     * enter code here
    */
    return true for valid
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "";
    do {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        if (isValidName(name)) {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

hasNextInt is not the best way to check if user has inputted number or not. You have to consider validation more thoroughly.

Comment: The OPs code is not beautiful, but it what way is it flawed?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, OP's first statement is looking hasNextInt(), when a user will keep hitting new line this method will create the garbage result that OP is seeing now. Hence, flawed.

Comment: *so that the scanner will ignore empty inputs.* - I guess I should read the question carefully ;-)

Comment: Your suggestion is helpful. But I should have specified that I wanted to provide custom error messages depending on the user's input. Not just validating.

Comment: @AlejandroMartinez, you can write your custom error in your isValidName function